# Any way to make if comparison faster while iterating through a column in a for cycle (PANDAS)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I am iterating through a column of a pandas df like this:

```
index | Creative Size     | Formato(IAB)
____________________________________
1     | '320x50'          | 
2     | 'something else'  |
3     | 'some string'     |
```

My code is this:

```
count=0
DB2_NO_YOUTUBE_NO_VIDEO.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
for i in DB2_NO_YOUTUBE_NO_VIDEO['Creative Size']:
    if i == '300x100' or i == '320x250' or i == '320x50' or i == '600x150':
        DB2_NO_YOUTUBE_NO_VIDEO.loc[count, 'Formato(IAB)']='DISPLAY STD'
    count= count+1
```

It compares the string of the row in the column with the specified condition and, in the event the condition is true, it substitutes the corresponding value in another column (Formato(IAB)) with the value 'DISPLAY STD'. It is very slow.
Could you suggest any improvement to make it faster?

Comment: `df.loc[df['Creative Size'].isin(list_of_acceptable_values), 'Format'] = 'STD'`. Apply lower-case mapping etc as needed.

Comment: Generally, in pandas/numpy programming there are many operations to avoid `for` looping.